# Im trying to print the strongly connected componets but i keep getting memory error

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "Appasa.h" 

Appasa::Appasa(){}

std::list<std::list<int>*>* Appasa::getSCComponents(std::list<int>* graph []){

    int V = sizeof(graph);
    //this.graph = graph; 
    std::stack<int>* mystack = new std::stack<int>();
    bool* visited = new bool[V];
    int* low = new int[V];

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++){

        if (!visited[i])
            dfs(v);
    }

    return sccComp;

}

void Appasa::dfs(int v){

    int preCounter = 0;
    //int* low; 
    int min;

    low[v] = preCounter++;
    visited[v] = true;
    mystack->push(v);
    min = low[v];

    for (int w = 0; w < sizeof(graph); w++){

        if (!visited[v])
            dfs(w);
        if (low[w] < min)
            min = low[w];
    }

    if (min < low[v]){
        low[v] = min;
        return;
    }

    std::list<int>* component = new std::list<int>();
    int w;

    w = mystack->top();
    mystack->pop();
    component->push_back(w);
    low[w] = V;

    std::list<std::list<int>*>* sccComp = new std::list<std::list<int>*>();

    while (w != v)
        sccComp->push_back(component);


}

int main(){

    int vertices, edges;
    int src, dest;

    scanf("%d%d", &vertices, &edges);
    std::list<int>* graph = new std::list<int>[vertices];

    for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++){
        graph[i] = std::list<int>();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= vertices; i++){
        scanf("%d%d", &src, &dest);
        graph[src].push_front(dest);
    }


    Appasa* a = new Appasa();



    //std::list<std::list<int>*>* sc = a->getSCComponents(&graph); 

    std::cout << "sc" << std::endl;
    getchar();

}
```

and when i use the input per example
`2 2` it immediatly answers with

> `Unhandled exception at 0x01256b4b in ASA.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfe01.`

Am i creating the graph the wrong way?

Comment: Please tag with the language you're using (and what does this have to do with version control?)

Comment: Dont know how that tag got in there sry

Comment: Can you please also add the declaration of Appasa? (Appasa.h) Either way, I think you are abusing pointers and leaking everything you allocate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from 1 to n (inclusive), you'll have to declare & initialize the garph as follows:

```
std::list<int>* graph = new std::list<int>[vertices+1];
```

This should get rid of that error you were getting here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= edges; i++){
     graph[i] = std::list<int>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! sorry about the messy question first time making a question in stack over flow :) 

Thanks!!!

Comment: If this was the answer that solved your problem, please click the check mark icon at the left of the post. Have a nice day!